# Restricting Excel Macros to the current file

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the settings (in the file or the program) so that instead of defaulting to "All Open Workbooks", the Macros are available only to "This Workbook" or the file itself?

Please note that the Macros are already created. I can see the "Macros in:" drop box at the bottom of the "Macro" pop-up. I just need to be able to change it away from the default of "All Open Workbooks".

There must be a simple solution, but I cannot seem to find it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Had a quick look and not entirely sure if this is possible. I will keep looking though. What is the purpose of keeping the dialog box to show macros in `thisworkbook` only?

Comment: You can't alter that behaviour of the macros dialog.

Comment: @Rory Yeah I didnt think it was possible as I couldn't find anything. JA76 - there might be other ways if this is nessesary. However would involve changing a lot on the Excel ribbon. And then creating a userform to show all the public macros instead

Comment: @Sam Seems like a lot of effort for a mild irritant... ;)

Comment: @Rory it does. However I always like a challenge. But does seem like a bit excessive.

Comment: I want my Excel files to not be able to access similarly named macros (which likely do not do the same thing) in other of my Excel files. I have built numerous files for educational purposes (I teach). It would be nice to know that my students are able to operate the files independently of any other file(s) which may be open at the time. Maybe I can build a Macro to precede the other Macros which will change the setting. Would that even work?